# Linear regression or other statistical hypotheses test needed for this data?

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance

I'm trying to analyse whether the balance of framing of the issue in question has significantly changed since 2012. Specifically, my research hypotheses are that the *proportion* of Frames 1 & 2 has decreased since 2012, and that the *proportion* of Frames 3,4,5,6,& 7 have increased since 2012 as per the results in the second table, and I am interested in the trend over the time as opposed to the change between two specific years. Given that the data is originally categorical, I am unsure as to whether a simple linear regression is sufficient for analysing the change in proportions, or whether I need to conduct a chi-squared test or other statistical test to answer this validly, so I'd really appreciate any help!

[image: Figure 1: Total Number of Frames]

[image: Figure 2: Proportion of Frames]

Comment: Cn you tell us what a "frame" is and what the change over time might represent?

Comment: A 'frame' here refers to how the an issue is being presented. For example, a conflict may be 'framed' as problematic due to its impact on economic prosperity, or due to its impact on political stability, or due to its impact on human welfare etc.. The change in 'framing' over time refers to how the emphasis of arguments has shifted over time. For example, if the proportion of frame 1 (economic stability) significantly decreases over time, it shows that economic stability is now less talked about compared to the other issues. Thanks!

Comment: How were these "frames" sampled?

Comment: The results presented show the frequency and proportion of frames for my entire dataset. I collected 550 documents from 2012-2022 and identified the presence and frequency of the different frames in each document (where one document could have multiple frames). I am not trying to infer the change in framing for a wider population - just whether the proportion of frames in this dataset has changed significantly over time as per the hypotheses in the original post. Thanks!